# If user click within my X element, don't show my test message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div class="topImg">
    <div id="maisinfo"><p id="show">Test</p></div> //show test text
    <div class="topImgIcon">
       <img src="img/icon.png" class="topImgIcon"><span class="tittle">Icon</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want if user click in my `<a class="imgClose">` will show my `<p>` element inside `#maisinfo` id

My jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(".topImg").prepend('<div class="topImg"><a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/fechar.png"></a></div>');

      $("#maisinfo").hide(); 
      //show and dont show the <p> element dont work
      $("#show").bind("click",function(){
        $("#maisinfo").slideToggle("slow");
          return false;
        });
    });
```

My div "#maisinfo" will show one form if user click inside my X element (my X element was inside the `a href` img src inside my jQuery after my test works.

My X element inside jQuery:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us that `<a class='imgClose'>` looks like?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain properly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on("click",'.imgClose',function(){
   $("#maisinfo").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".topImg").prepend('<div class="topImg"><a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty4bj.jpg" height="20" width="20"></a></div>');

  $("#maisinfo").hide(); 
  
  //show and dont show the <p> element dont work
  $(document).on("click",'.imgClose',function(){
    $("#maisinfo").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topImg">
  <div id="maisinfo"><p id="show">Test</p></div><br>
  <div class="topImgIcon">
    <img src="img/icon.png" class="topImgIcon"><span class="tittle">Icon</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:- i have used an icon to show you that it's working.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi  glad to help you.:):)